# trouble detecting squares using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find the number of squares using the square demo from OpenCV.

[image: 1]

I was able to get only

[image: 2]

Is it possible to find the squares in at least one row and one column so that we can find the total square present.

Is there any optimization that can be done?

Comment: If you have 3 corner points and square location step, you can find total number of squares. N=(W/s)*(H/s).  W - board width, H-board height, s - square step.

Comment: can you help with example code to find the H,W,s ?

Comment: You have squares on sample image above, find minAreaRect  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect you'll get width and height, you have also small rectangles, find minimal distance between neighbours along sides of rectangle   you found with minAreaRect and you'll get step along  x and along y.

Comment: Maybe an HoG object detector would be better.
http://blog.dlib.net/2014/02/dlib-186-released-make-your-own-object.html
I think your project is interesting. Could please provide  some more picture s of your breadboard? Than I will quickly evalute the method. And tell you ift works

Comment: @ R_Valdez This is something like cascade training in opencv. but i don't think its the right approach.

Comment: but sure you can [try].(http://i.imgsafe.org/761b70c.jpg)

Comment: @Andrey Smorodov will try. Thanks for your approach